# Lost rows when upgrading from MySQL 5.6 to 8.0

Tags: mysql

I tried to migrate the database of existing application from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 8.0

I have created the backup .sql file from old engine and deplayed it to new 8.0 server - I received no errors , no warnings - process finished successfully.

**BUT** - my database size was 62 MB in MySQL 5.6 and when I moved it to MySQL 8.0 size changed to 56 MB. I have tried to check which tables where different and noticed that in some tabled the number of rows decreased.

Can anyone tell me why such strange thing happend? Why database size and row number decreased- even throw the process finished without errors and warnings.

Are there some important thinks that I need to know in migration process - that will allow me not to loose any data?

Comment: If you went 5.6 to 5.7, ran mysql upgrade, (to update system tables) then upgraded to 5.7, ran mysql upgrade, installed 8, AND again ran mysql upgrade all should be good.

Comment: Assuming you did everything correctly, then I'd guess it just was able to compress the data a bit during the process, and/or the storage format in 8.0 is a bit more efficient. The size of the DB file is unlikely, _by itself_, to indicate any data loss.

Comment: however if you're claiming that rows are missing, then 1) ensure they were present in the backup file (and not added to the database after the time that the backup was taken), 2) if that doesn't explain it, you'll have to explain to us in detail exactly what process you followed and what exact commands you ran, in case there is some mistake in your deployment.

Comment: Is this lost rows as in `SELECT COUNT(*)` shows fewer rows, or are you depending on the wildly inaccurate results of `SHOW TABLE STATUS`? The latter can be off by *several orders of magnitude* because it computes row counts based on data size divided by approximate average record size, a far from scientific method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have few things listed out.

1) Total number of tables in 5.6

2) highest rows tables.

First try to restore dump in same 5.6 version, double check above information.

decreasing size in few MB's is very common because of compression and restoration is different at another server.

All you need to make sure total number of rows should not decreased.